# HTML element not getting focus on tab but on shift+tab is accessible

Tags: html, css

I have a structure like this:

```
<div> <a href='#'>Hyperlink</a> </div>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Row1</td>
      <td><button>Click</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row2</td>
      <td><button>Click</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row3</td>
      <td><button>Click</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I am not able to navigate to buttons using tab but on shift+tab they are getting focus and can be accessed. A lot of classes have been used with each HTML element but tabindex has not been used.

What can be the issue? Please help.

Comment: its working..getting focus

Comment: Did you find a solution?? I have the same problem except the tabindex attribute is already set.. The problem is only in firefox, in chrome it works perfectly. I wonder if it is a problem with tables.

Comment: Elements inside table receives focus when the table div has a tabindex="0". But I wish there is a better way to make the elements focusable

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the global tabindex attribute in HTML.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp

```
tabindex="n"
```

You can give elements the sequence they should be tabbed in, and that would most likely fix any tabbing focus issues you have right now.

Comment: I do not want to provide tabindex explicitly

Comment: Can you explain your reasons?

Comment: Using tab index is not feasible for a dynamic page with a lot of form controls or other elements. I'm facing flip side of this issue, Tab is working fine from top to button, but shift + tab misses for some buttons

Answer (score -1):

You have to define `tabindex` for the elements and use a bit jQuery

```js
$(function(){
  $('#anchor').click(function(){
    $(this).html('Pres Tab now');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  position:absolute;
  top:-100px;
}
input{
  width:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<a href='#' id="anchor" tabindex="1">Click me</a>
</div>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Row1</td><td><button tabindex="2">Click</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row2</td><td><button tabindex="3">Click</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row3</td><td><button tabindex="4">Click</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
  <div class="hidden"><input type="text" tabindex="5" onfocus="$('#anchor').focus()" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue should not be with tabindex because I am getting the focus with shift+tab but not only with tab.

Comment: @Ankita Is there any JS file linked with your html?

Comment: Yes. JS file is linked to the HTML.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so that it could be easy to find out the problem?

Answer (score -1):

You Need One Dummy Input For Rotating Tab Order It Is In Hidden Mode

```js
$(function(){
  $('#anchor').click(function(){
    $(this).html('Check Tab now');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  position:absolute;
  top:-100px;
}
input{
  width:0px;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
  color:#ff8800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<a href='#' id="anchor" tabindex="1">Click me</a>
</div>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Row1</td><td><button tabindex="2">Click</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row2</td><td><button tabindex="3">Click</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Row3</td><td><button tabindex="4">Click</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
  <div class="hidden"><input type="text" tabindex="5" onfocus="$('#anchor').focus()" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not want to provide tabindex explicitly. Button is getting focussed on shift+tab whereas not getting focussed on moving forward using tab.